# typeahead.js load error "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, typeahead.js, autosuggest

oHi guys, on page load i see this error in console:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined"

i have this code in head:

```
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Typeahead -->
<script src="js/typeahead/typeahead.js"></script>
```

I have no idea whats happening, and i cannot google anything about this kind of typeahead.js problem.
I will appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: check the network tab of developer tools(F12 > Network) to see if all your scripts are getting loaded correctly

Comment: Yes, all scripts are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get your tipeahead script? Looks like it relies on [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/)

We need more information anyway (stacktrace, how you load the typeahead script, and its content).

Comment: I downloaded it from GitHub https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js then i copied bloodhound, common and typeahead directories from src directory to my js directory and then i added code to <head> and tried to run page and i have just mentioned and only one error in console on page load.

Comment: Have tried underscore.js, new error appeared. Then i tried just to load lodash.js and now i have no errors on load. Thank you very much. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was referencing typeahead.bundle.js from the /src/ (source) folder of the bower package instead of the /dist/ (distribution) folder by mistake.

By pointing at the /dist/typeahead.bundle.js instead it works fine without the need to add Underscore.js or Lo-Dash manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#getting-started) you'll see the instructions for installing this library. The `_` that it's missing is defined in `bloodhound.js`. You can see where it is defined [in this file](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/bloodhound.js) around line 6.

Try adding that link before your `typeahead` script and see if that fixes the problem.

This all may be included with the typeahead script you're loading, which would make my answer wrong, but try it out and see if that fixes it.

Edit: [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/common/utils.js#L7) is the definitions of `_` in the github repo

Comment: i loaded bloodhound.js too, it produced this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: tokenizers is not defined". I loaded tokenizers.js which was in same directory as bloodhound.js and it solved this prblem. It didn't solve problem with _. I need to load Lo-dash as first anyway.